# Were there fewer first-home buyers in Australia in 2017 than seventh-home buyers?

Tags: economics, australia

An [ABC news item](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-12-08/queensland-rental-laws-on-cusp-of-change/10595628) today quoted a claim about the Australian property market without any indication that they verified it:

> [Queensland] State Housing Minister Mick De Brenni said that last year more Australians bought their seventh home than those who bought their first [...]

I see this statement as ambiguous: it could refer to:

- people who grew their current real-estate portfolio from six houses to seven, or
- people who have bought homes seven times in the life, but may have sold up to six of them.

I find both claims extraordinary, but the second is a softer claim, so it seems fairer to the claimant to use that interpretation.

Did more home-buyers in Australia buy a home for the seventh time than the first in 2017?

---

It appears the original claim was quietly removed from the article after posting this question. (Hat-tip @Daniel and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AustralianPolitics/comments/a4glmp/last_year_more_australians_bought_their_seventh/))

However, I believe the claim is still widely believed, based on the number of mentions on social media, including post-removal.

Twitter examples: [@TeamSJW](https://twitter.com/TeamSJW/status/1071761457262428160), [zeroxcliche](https://twitter.com/zeroxcliche/status/1071652708342353920), [@benhr](https://twitter.com/ben_hr), [@YsadoraFemme](https://twitter.com/YsadoraFemme/status/1072065969198030849), [@gritfish](https://twitter.com/gritfish/status/1071886496628502529), [@laura_e_wynne](https://twitter.com/laura_e_wynne/status/1071867062794969088)

Comment: That line of the article has quietly gone down the memory hole https://www.reddit.com/r/AustralianPolitics/comments/a4glmp/last_year_more_australians_bought_their_seventh/

Comment: Related meta post: [*Does a notable claim remain notable if notable sources remove the claim?*](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4292/5337)

Comment: Q: What would be the relevance of this claim, i.e. what do they actually mean to say that they use this data tidbit for?

Comment: Dammit. My Facebook feed still has several examples of the claim.

Comment: @JanDoggen: The implication is that housing has become unobtainable for young people, who are now forced to rent from rich landlords who can afford multiple properties.

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question as off-topic because, while I personally believe it is still notable (judging by my Facebook wall), there is no notable claim cited here; it seems to have been quietly removed from the article. The question should be edited with other versions of the claim before reopening.

Comment: I reopened after adding more notability references. Let me know if you are unhappy with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the fact is not true. It appears to have been a mistake by the the Minister Mick De Brenni, that was not fact-checked by the ABC journalist.

[The New Daily](https://thenewdaily.com.au/money/property/2018/12/10/first-home-buyers-factcheck-did-more-people-buy-their-seventh-home-than-their-first/) contacted the politician:

> “The statistics referenced in that quote were misinterpreted from a [Misha Zelinski article for the Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com.au/misha-zelinksy/how-property-addicts-have-locked-young-australians-out-of-the-ho_a_22076682/),” a spokesperson for the minister told The New Daily.
>
> “The quote has now been removed from the relevant ministerial media statement, and we have contacted the ABC to get it removed from their article.”